# Outlook Add-in (VSTO 4) - VS2010 auto-referencing older VSTO assembly when adding new Form Region

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook add-in project that was first developed in Visual Studio 2008, using VSTO 3.0 and targeting Outlook 2007. This project had a couple of custom Form Regions that added functionality to specific AppointmentItem and TaskItem inspectors, which were successfully added to the project and worked fine.

Late last year we made the jump to VS2010, and at the same time made the decision to target both the 2007 and 2010 versions of Outlook. Project conversion seemed to go smoothly, I changed the target of the project to use VSTO 4.0 (adding in version handling code per the suggestion at this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/06/04/creating-an-add-in-for-office-2007-and-office-2010-that-quot-lights-up-quot-on-office-2010-mclean-schofield.aspx), and everything seemed fine. The existing form regions work without problem in both 2007 and 2010.

I'm adding some new functionality to the add-in, and went to add a new Form Region to the project today as part of that work. When I did so, VS2010 automatically added a VSTO 3 assembly to the project (specifically: Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.v9.0.dll) which caused all kinds of namespace collisions and actively screwed up the Form Region designer.

I've tried everything I can think of to prevent VS2010 from automatically adding this assembly - including hand-editing the csproj file to make sure there are no VSTO 3 references - yet this behavior persists. Anytime I add a Form Region (using Add New Item -> Outlook Form Region), VS2010 insists on adding the above-referenced assembly, wreaking havoc on my project. Has anyone experienced this behavior in VS2010? And is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if any more info needs to be provided.

Comment: Well, I couldn't find a way to stop VS2010 from auto-adding the reference to the older VSTO assembly, but I did find a workaround. Thanks to the excellent info at Beth Massi's place (http://bit.ly/tNcVGQ) and MSDN (http://bit.ly/tssF5b), after adding a new form region (which is essentially just a user control with extra VSTO bits), I removed the ref to the old assembly, and then hand-rolled the code-behind for the form region. Restart VS2010 and all is right with the form region again (including designer support).  It's not great and I'd rather not have to touch auto-gen'd code, but it works.